# align text and images inside the button image

Tags: html, css

to css . I have a button image inside the button image the txt should be in left side and another image should be in right side. the one i did is its all in the center. can some help me? thank you..

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      button {
        /* padding-top: 100px; */
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url("https://www.searchpng.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Game-Button-PNG-copy.jpg");
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button">
      <span>test</span>
      <img
        src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/metamask-2728406-2261817.png"
        width="60"
      />
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can access the code here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-bhaskara-7bueu?file=/index.html:0-805

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      button {
        /* padding-top: 100px; */
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url("https://www.searchpng.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Game-Button-PNG-copy.jpg");
        height: 100%;
        max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
      }
     button span {
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    color: white;
    top: 29px;
}
button img{position: relative;
    right: -28%;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <button type="button">
          <span>test</span>
          <img
            src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/metamask-2728406-2261817.png"
            width="60"
          />
        </button>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very muchhh!! really appreciate your help 

Comment: it's my pleasure, If any help require for css,html and WordPress i always Appericate

Comment: Hi very sorry, can i ask how can i make it responsive? cause when i tried its not responsive 

Comment: yes do it responsive but image change want to without outside space

Comment: Thank you very much u really help me a lot